# Calculate element height & add to margin-top via JS

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, each

I am looking to find the specific height of an element, if there is a difference add it to the top of the element, therefore push the element down using margin-top.

```
var targetImage         = $(".target-image"),
    targetImageHeight   = targetImage.innerHeight(),
    maxHeight           = 175,
    topMargin           = maxHeight - targetImageHeight;

targetImage.each(function(){
    if (targetImageHeight < maxHeight){

        targetImage.css({
            "margin-top": topMargin
        })
    }   
});
```

However this would loop around for all the listed items of the same class.

Comment: If you are trying to keep images aligned to the bottom of a containing element I think you can use: vertical-align:bottom;

Comment: my element is a block element not inline. I believe the solution you recommended is not functional on display:block elements.

Comment: Have you tried display: inline-block?  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: nope no luck here.. Does not seem to work..